# trying to write integers into file genreates random characters in C language

Tags: c, fwrite

I'm trying to make a random `input.txt` file generator in `C language` but I keep getting random characters in the output file. I tried using both `putw()` and `fwrite()` but I get the same result.

```c
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        ran_numb = rand()%(ram_size-1);
        // printf("%d", ran_numb);
        // int err = putw(ran_numb, fp);
        fwrite(&ran_numb, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
        fputc('\n', fp);
    }
```

output file:

```
~   
ô  
  
u   
?  
  
  
   
{  
ø  
  
È   
Õ   
å  
    
×  
¡
```

full code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv){
    generate_input_file(2048);

}

void generate_input_file(int ram_size){
    int ran_numb = 0;
    FILE *fp = fopen("input.txt", "w");;

    if(fp == NULL){
        printf("can't open file!");
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        ran_numb = rand()%(ram_size-1);
        // printf("%d", ran_numb);
        // int err = putw(ran_numb, fp);
        fwrite(&ran_numb, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
        fputc('\n', fp);
    }


}
```

Comment: If you write binary data into a file, you should open it with a hex editor. It's not readable text. If you want readable text, you should use `fprintf` instead of `fwrite`.

Comment: Besides that, you have multiple issues: 1) You must declare any function you call before you call it. 2) You should call `srand(time(NULL));` once in your program before you call `rand()`. 3) If you cannot open the file, you should terminate your program. Otherwise you will pass a `NULL` pointer to `fwrite` causing undefined behaviour.

Comment: You say "I'm trying to make a random … file generator in C language but I keep getting random characters in the output file".  On the face of it, that sounds like 'success'.  What sort of random output are you hoping for?  Presumably, not what you're getting.

Comment: thanks, but what is the best way to terminate the program after a failed `fopen`?

Comment: @fayssalelansari To terminate, return a non-zero exit code from main (pick a number that best represents the error)
`if(fp == NULL){ printf("can't open file!"); return 1; }`

Comment: Print an error message on `stderr`, preferably including the program name (`argv[0]`), the file name, and the failure reason (via `errno` and `strerror()`).  Then call `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`.  If the program name isn't available, omit it (often requires library support).

Comment: If you detect an error within a function, you can either report that error to the caller using an appropriate error return value. Or you could immediately terminate the program using `exit(-1)` which is same as `return -1;` from `main`. Printing a proper error message first, would also be a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the help of the comments, this is the final program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include "simulator.h"

int main (int argc, char* argv){
    generate_input_file(2048);
}

void  Gen_Input_File(int ram_size){
    int ran_numb = 0;
    const char filename[] = "input.txt"

    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "w");;
    if(fp == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file '%s' for writing: %s\n", filename, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
        ran_numb = rand()%(ram_size-1);
        fprintf(fp, "%d\n", ran_numb);
    }

}
```

I've added the missing headers to stop warnings.

Comment: You should report the file name in the error message, and ideally the error message should go to standard error (which is for printing error messages) and not on standard output.  I'd argue that you should never call `fopen()` with a string literal for a file name, because you either have to repeat the name in the error message or omit it from the error message, neither of which is good.  Use: `const char filename[] = "input.txt"; FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "w"); … fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file '%s' for writing: %s\n", filename, strerror(errno));`